# Will there be a proper subset B(x,d) of B(x,D) in a metric space?

Tags: general-topology

I am working on this:

If $(X,\rho)$ is a non-discrete metric space, $x\in X$ is not an isolated point. Assume $U$ is an open set which contains $x$.
It's obvious that $\exists B(x,D) \subset U.$

I suppose that there must be a proper subset $B(x,d) \subsetneqq B(x,D)$

Here is my proof:

First of all, U can't be finite. If so, assume $U=\{x,x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, then take $0<\varepsilon<min \{\rho(x,x_1),...,\rho(x,x_n)\}$.

Then take $B(x,\varepsilon)$. By defination of $\varepsilon$, $B(x,\varepsilon)=\{x\}$. However, $x$ is not an isolated point. So U is not finite.

Then,take $y\ne x \in B(x,D)$, and $\frac{\rho(x,y)}{2}$ as d, then  $B(x,d) \subsetneqq B(x,D)$.

My tutor said there is something wrong with my proof. But I can't see where's the problem.

If there really something wrong? If so ,where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $B(x,D) \neq \{x\}$ because we assumed $x$ is not an isolated point. So there is some $y \neq x$ such that $y \in B(x,D)$.
But then, setting $d=\rho(x,y)>0$, we know $B(x,d) \subsetneqq B(x,D)$: the inclusion part follows from $z \in B(x, d) \to \rho(x,z) < d = \rho(x,y) < D$ and the $\neq$-part follows from $y \notin B(x,d)$ (as $\rho(x,y) = d \not< d$). QED. No infinite or not distinction is needed (though it *is* true that any ball around a non-isolated point must be infinite in a metric space; this essentially uses your first argument).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your argument that $U$ is infinite; it's correct, but it's not really relevant.  All you really need is the last line ("take $y \ne x$..."), and to get there all you need is to show that $B(x,D)$ contains at least one point other than $x$.  But that's immediate because if it didn't then $x$ would be isolated.

Comment: Can I just apply the previous argument on the B(x,d) to prove it contains other points?

Comment: @yLccc: You don’t need to prove that $B(x,d)$ contains other points. The *only* thing that you need to prove is that there is a $d<D$ such that $B(x,d)\subsetneqq B(x,D)$.